# Conditional test for DNSError IsNotFound

Tags: go

I'm using the net package to perform DNS lookups, such as:

```
hostnames, err := net.LookupAddr("192.168.0.1")
if err != nil {
    // Do something
}
```

Instead of boldly (foolishly?) assuming any error means the same thing, I'd like to check the status of the IsNotFound bool in [DNSError](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#DNSError).  Can anyone provide an idiomatic example of how to structure a conditional that checks the error is a DNSError and, if it is, that the IsNotFound bool is true/false?

Thanks

Comment: [The `errors` package provides idiomatic examples.](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by casting error to DNSError.

```
if err != nil {
    if e, ok := err.(*net.DNSError); ok && e.IsNotFound {
        // err is a NotFound DNSError
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```